# Exporting / publishing a file on Github

Tags: github

I have a few .js, .html, and .css files on my GitHub. I'd like to make these files publicly accessible as libraries to anyone with an internet connection.

Is this possible?

Currently, the URLs to my pages are GitHub versions of the code not the actual file. I just want a URL for the actual file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The raw files for GitHub repositories are stored at:

```
https://raw.github.com/user/repository/branch/filename
```

For example:

```
https://raw.github.com/slhck/dotfiles/master/.zshrc
```

You can access this file by clicking the *Raw* button for a file:

[image]